# PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException >> Class 'app\controllers\ALUMNI_MEMBER_DETAIL' not found

Tags: php, sql, yii2, yii2-basic-app

currently I am using this guide for Yii2 tutorial: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-databases.html

I tried to modify the Country example to my own tables based on my Oracle SQL database and I kept on getting this error.

[image]

Here is my Model(AlumniReportListing.php);

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class AlumniReportListing extends ActiveRecord
{

}
```

Here is the controller(AlumniReportListingController);

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\data\Pagination;
use app\models\AlumniReportListing;

class AlumniReportListingController extends Controller
{
public function actionIndex()
{
    $query = ALUMNI_MEMBER_DETAIL::find();

    $pagination = new Pagination([
        'defaultPageSize' => 5,
        'totalCount' => $query->count(),
    ]);

    $student = $query->orderBy('AMD_STUD_ID')
        ->offset($pagination->offset)
        ->limit($pagination->limit)
        ->all();

    return $this->render('index', [
        'student' => $student,
        'pagination' => $pagination,
    ]);
}
}
```

and finally the View(index.php);

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\LinkPager;
?>
<h1>Alumni Student Listing</h1>
<ul>
<?php foreach ($student as $stud): ?>
    <li>
        <?= Html::encode("{$stud->AMD_STUD_ID} ({$stud->AMD_MEM_ID})") ?>:
        <?= $stud->AMD_NAME ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>

<?= LinkPager::widget(['pagination' => $pagination]) ?>
```

I believe I need to do something to create the ALUMNI_MEMBER_DETAIL to make it exist as an object and but I am quite confused on how to do it as the Country example works fine as it is.

Comment: Where is defined class ALUMNI_MEMBER_DETAIL?
Or it is name of table? If it is name of table, you must create class for this table and use this class like `use app\models\AlumniMemberDetail`;

Comment: @mnv yes it is the name of a table. Do i create this class as a model? And do i need to add any functions in it? I don't really understand why the AlumniRecordListing can't be used. In fact, how does the model even read the table only with the class name?

Comment: yes, as model. what contains in app\models\AlumniReportListing? Also, if you trying to use find(),  you can read about Actice Record in Yii2: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html

Comment: @mnv Thank you! I think I'm getting the hang of this. First time using a framework!